# Store Lock Issue on Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, apache-storm

Getting following exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting
>   org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:335)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:108)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:95)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:67)
>           at com.tpgsi.mongodb.dataPollingWithOplog.ORBCreateLink.main(ORBCreateLink.java:62)
>   Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@5b6ca687' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:331)
>           ... 6 more Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain l  file:
>   /home/aps/neo4j-community-2.2.3/CompleteTest/store_lock. Please ensure
>   no other process is using this database, and that the directory is
>   writable (required even for read-only access)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:78)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
>           ... 8 more Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
>           at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1087)
>           at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1154)
>           at org.neo4j.io.fs.StoreFileChannel.tryLock(StoreFileChannel.java:135)
>           at org.neo4j.io.fs.FileLock.wrapFileChannelLock(FileLock.java:38)
>           at org.neo4j.io.fs.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:99)
>           at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:85)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)

I have one process which will create graph and on completion of this i have one more process to create few more relationship on top of if. But i am getting above exception while running the second process after completion of first process. I checked the data directory of Neo4j is not been used by any process but still getting lock issue.

I ran once a piece of code to create the graph.

```
   static GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = null; 
   static GraphDatabaseService graphdb  = null;  

  static{
dbFactory =new GraphDatabaseFactory();
  graphdb  = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(com.tpgsi.mongodb.dataPollingWithOplog.CommonConstants.NEO4J_DATA_DIRECTORY);
  }

  try{
Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx();
  try
 {
    // creating Node and relationships

    tx.success();
  } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.failure();
            e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       tx.close();
    }
      }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

I have created graphdb object as global variable and using that everywhere. Only transaction, i  am closing. I am not using registerShutDownHook() and shutdown function for graphdb object. The reason i am not using these functions are because, i am running this in storm environment with multiple executors and if we will shutdown this then for every thread i have to create it again which is also not good.
I am thinking not shutting down the graphdb could be the reason. 
If i am running the same code with One executor it works fine but with multiple executor getting Lock issue. 
Can anybody tell me what i have to do to get ride of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was executing my code with multiple worker and executor in storm environment. As multiple worker were creating multiple graphdb install and i was getting store lock exception. I changed the number of worker to 1 and to create graphdb object i have written singleton class to ensure i am creating only one graphdb object at a time and it's a gloabal variable.

Answer (score 0):

A graph database instance is thread-safe so you can use it across all bolts, just make it accessible as a global variable.

Only one GDB at a time can access a store-directory.

Otherwise create a service that your storm-bolts access/use via another protocol e.g. http or binary.

Comment: Thanks Michael, will try as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. But my mistake is I executed the program while the server is running. If I stop the server, then the program executed successfully.

Comment: If neo4j is already running and running application on top of it will definitely give the lock exception.